# Save a list to a .txt file with lines in between each value

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I found this answer (stackoverflow.com/questions/33686747/save-a-list-to-a-txt-file), which is great but it doesn't show me how to put the values on separate lines in the text file created.

Here is my code if it helps:

> heightandweight = ['James', 73, 1.82, 'Peter', 78, 1.80, 'Beth', 65, 1.53, 'Mags', 66, 1.50, 'Joy', 62, 1.34]
>
> with open("heightandweight.txt", "w") as output:
>
> > output.write(str(heightandweight))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate through the list, adding each line individually, adding "\n" to indicate you want a new line:

```
with open("heightandweight.txt", "w") as output:
    for i in heightandweight:
        output.write(str(i) + "\n")
```

Gives

```
James
73
1.82
Peter
78
1.8
Beth
65
1.53
Mags
66
1.5
Joy
62
1.34
```

If you want to add a name and their height and weight on the same line, then things are a little more complicated:

```
with open("heightandweight.txt", "w") as output:
    for i, name in enumerate(heightandweight, 0):
        if i % 3 == 0:
            output.write("%s %i %.2f\n" % (heightandweight[i], heightandweight[i+1], heightandweight[i+2]))
```

This uses `enumerate` to get an integer value, `i`, which increments by one everytime the for loop iterates. It then checks it it's a multiple of three, if it is, then it writes it to the file using [string formatting](https://pyformat.info/). Here's the output:

```
James 73 1.82
Peter 78 1.80
Beth 65 1.53
Mags 66 1.50
Joy 62 1.34
```

This isn't really the best way to do it. You're better off using a list of lists: `[['James', 73, 1.82], ['Peter', 78, 1.80], ['Beth', 65, 1.53], ['Mags', 66, 1.50], ['Joy', 62, 1.34]]`